# Pagination using Bootstrap 3&DataTables align vertical instead of horizontal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, datatables

I'm using Bootstrap 3 & DataTables for using table sort and search and the page part is not at the correct place.
I've tried to change the position and display but without success.

[image: Pagination Vertical instead of Horizontal]

My HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Statistics</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/clientSide.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tableSort').dataTable();
});    
</script>

<body ng-controller="ToDoCtrl">
<header>
   <div class="headerGallery">

       <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var options = { $AutoPlay: false };
            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
            });
        </script>

    <div id="slider1_container">
        <div id="slider1" u="slides" div u="slides">
            <div><img src="images/headerIMG1.jpg"/></div>
            <div><img src="images/headerIMG2.jpg"/></div>
        </div>
            <div class="nav">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="shop.html">SHOP</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FAVOURITES</a></li>
                <li><a href="articles.html">ARTICLES</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
</header>

<div id="articleWrapper">
    <section id="logo1"></section>
        <section class="aboutTitle1">
        <h3>STATISTICS</h3>
        </section>   
        <br>
        <section id="search">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                      <div class="input-group form">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                           <span class="input-group-btn">
                             <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
                           </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
       </section>
        <h3>Name: <strong>Here we need to bring the user name.</strong></h3>
          <h2>Product Likes</h2>
          <p>In this part you can see how many likes each and every item of yours got.</p>
        <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="tableStatistics">
          <table class="table table-hover" id="tableSort" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Amount of Likes</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>john@example.com</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Mary</td>
                <td>Moe</td>
                <td>mary@example.com</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>July</td>
                <td>Dooley</td>
                <td>july@example.com</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    


<div class="openfooterblack" id="openfooter" ng-show="footer==1">

    <section id="footerPanel">
        <section id="emptyPanel"></section>
        <section class ="loginPanel">
        <form name="login" action="index_submit" method="get">
             <ul>
             <input class="inputLogin" type="email" name="usermail" ng-model="usermail" required></li>
                <li><label for="usermail">User Name:</label></li>            
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <input class="inputLogin" type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" required></li>
                <li><label for="password">Password:</label></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <a class="forgotPassBtm" href="#">Forgot your Password</a>
            <a class="registrationBtm" href="#">Registration</a>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <input type="reset" class="resetbtn" value="">
          <input type="submit" class="submitbtn" ng-click="addLogin(usermail, password)" value="">
            </form>
        </section>
        <section class ="categoryPanel">
            <label id="categoryLabel">CATEGORY</label>

                  <div ng-repeat="category in todo.categories | orderBy:'name'">
                    <section class="categoryName"><a href="#">{{category.name}}</a>
                    </section>
                  </div>

        </section>
    </section>

</div>

<footer>
    <div id="login">
        <section class="loginbtnfooter">
        <a ng-click="footer=!footer" href="#"></a>
        </section>
        <section class="logoutbtnfooter">
        <a href="login.html"></a>
        </section>
    </div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS :

```
.tableStatistics {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.tableStatistics > a,p,thead,tbody,tr,h2 {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.table-hover tbody tr:hover td, .table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
  background-color: #CCC;
}

div.dataTables_length label {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #ffffff;
}

div.dataTables_info {
    padding-top: 8px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #ffffff;
}

div.dataTables_paginate {
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You're really including a lot more code than is necessary here, which makes it difficult to see what you've changed. Can you try to narrow down the included code to what is relevant to the pagination?

Comment: Where do you want the paging to appear in relation to the table?

Comment: Hi, it should be under the table.

Comment: The relevant div class name : tableStatistics.